# handling checbox in contact form

Tags: php

i am creating a php form and i followed the normal way for handling a check box
but however in this code it always prints no, whats the problem?

```
<form method="post" action="php/form.php">
  <div class="form-check pull-left">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="yes" name="check1">
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
</form>

if (isset($_POST['check1'])) {
  $check1 = "yes";
} else {
  $check1 = "no";
}
$body="check1: $check1";
mail('email@mail.com', $subject, $body)
```

i always receive email with no

Comment: Please try it: if (isset($_POST['check1']) && $_POST['check1'] == 'yes')

Comment: Post full code of your form.

Comment: @Scaffold first condition is already returning false, then how can condition be true, by adding one more AND condition?

Comment: @BanshiL.Dangi form is huge so i added the form tag

Comment: @Jamesmarcus Without looking at the form code, it is bit difficult to figure out the issue.

Comment: Try is : print_r($_POST);

Comment: @BanshiL.Dangi thats probably the part you care about

Comment: @Scaffold where should i add this?

Comment: before  if()  condition.

Comment: Do you have a parent if condition like this - if(isset($_POST['submit'])) where "submit" is name of your submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page first loads, nothing has been posted, therefore `$_POST` is empty and `$_POST['check1'] == NULL`.

Based on your logic, you are setting `check1` to `no` in this case and sending an email (even when nothing has been posted).

You should ensure something has been posted, which can be done by adding a `submit` button to your form

```
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit POST</button>
```

and checking for the existence of `$_POST['submit']`

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

All together:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-check pull-left">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="yes" name="check1">
            Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
        </label>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit POST</button>
    </div>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['check1'])) {
        $check1 = "yes";
    } else {
        $check1 = "no";
    }
    $body = "check1: $check1";
    mail('email@mail.com', $subject, $body)
}
```

This way, an email will only get sent when the user actually submits the form, NOT every time the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal if you don't have submit input.
And you wrap your mail function with checking if $_POST is not empty.

Try this :

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-check pull-left">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="yes" name="check1" checked>
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
<?php

if (isset ($_POST) && !empty ($_POST))
{
   if (isset($_POST['check1'])) {
     $check1 = "yes";
   } else {
     $check1 = "no";
   }
   $body="check1: $check1";
   mail('email@mail.com', $subject, $body)
}
```